# jquery flash plugin is showing nothing

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, audio, flash

I am using jquery flash plugin for showing audio clip i had tried in this fiddle .please check this fiddle http://www.jsfiddle.net/RCfkF/2/ the flash plugin is not showing any thing ,why please suggest .Thanks

I have implemented according to ClemDesm answer , but is not showing , please check the fiddle http://www.jsfiddle.net/RCfkF/2/

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your fiddle got bad markup.

Anyway, you don't use [the plugin](http://jquery.lukelutman.com/plugins/flash/) as it is shown on its [examples](http://jquery.lukelutman.com/plugins/flash/example-mp3.html) and [docs](http://jquery.lukelutman.com/plugins/flash/#features).

**You don't link to the mp3, but to a swf reading that mp3!**

From http://jquery.lukelutman.com/plugins/flash/example-mp3.html,

> Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[@href$="mp3"]').flash(
        { src: 'singlemp3player.swf', height: 20, width: 100 },
        { version: 7 },
        function(htmlOptions) {
            $this = $(this);
            htmlOptions.flashvars.file = $this.attr('href');
            $this.before($.fn.flash.transform(htmlOptions));                        
        }
    );
});
```

> Before:

```
<li><a href="sound.mp3">sound.mp3</a></li>
```

> After:

```
<li>
    <embed width="100" height="20" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="singlemp3player.swf" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" flashvars="file=sound.mp3"/>
    <a href="sound.mp3">sound.mp3</a>
</li>
```

---

This is how you might use the plugin (just a copy/paste of the example above)

http://www.jsfiddle.net/RCfkF/4/

Comment: Hi , ClemDesm Thanks for answer , and tried to implement accordingly, but there is some problem , Please check what is the problem http://www.jsfiddle.net/RCfkF/2/

Comment: Try to put an absolute url to `singlemp3player.swf` since `http://www.jsfiddle.net/singlemp3player.swf` doesn't exist ;)